# Null check operator used on a null value FutureBuilder<List<x>>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I cant run my system app because of this error. Can someone guide me please? What is my error ?.
Please guide me sir to your wonderful knowledge.

```
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<Plants>>
```

this is my plantpage list view

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<List<Plants>>(
      future: PlantsApi.getPlantsLocally(context),
      builder:(context, snapshot) {
        var users = snapshot.data! as List<Plants>;
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
          if (users != null && users.length > 0) {
            return Center(child: Text('error'),);
          }
          else {
           
            return buildPlants(users);
          }


Widget buildPlants(List<Plants> plants) => 
ListView.builder(
  
  itemCount: plants.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
    final plant = plants[index];
    return 
    
    ListTile (
      title: Text(plant.name ?? 'default'),
```

here is my database json. I already parse it using data class generator.

```
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ALOCASIA-ELEPHANT EARS",
            "image": "assets/images/ALOCASIA.jpeg",
            "descript": "Alocasia plant (Alocasia mortfontanensis) is a hybrid species between Alocasia longiloba and Alocasia sanderiana. The Alocasia is known for its large leaves and wide variety of cultivars within the species. Alocasia plant is native to tropical Asia and Australia.",
            "charac": [{
              "planttype": "Herb",
              "lifespan": "Perennial",
              "bloomtime": "Spring, summer",
              "plantheight": "1-2 feet",
              "spread": "7 feet",
              "leafColor": "PurpleGreenGreySilver"
            }
            ],
            "scienclass": [
                {
                "genus": "Alocasia - Elephant's-ears, Taro, Kris plant",
                "family": " Araceae - Arum, Aroids ",
                "order": "Alismatales - Water plantains and allies",
                "classes": "Liliopsida - Monocotyledons, Monocots ",
                "phylum":"Tracheophyta - Vascular plants, Seed plants, Ferns, Tracheophytes"
            }
            ],
            "pestdesease": " Stem rot, crown rot, root rot, leaf spot, mealy bugs, aphids",
            "requirements":[{
                "difficultyrating": "Alocasia plant is super easy to take care of, with resistance to almost all pests and diseases. It is a perfect option for gardeners with brown thumbs.",
                "sunlight": "Full shade to partial sun",
                "hardenesszone": " 9-11 ",
                "soil": "Loose, fertile and well-drained humus soil"
            }
         ],
            "careguide":[
                {
                "water": "Moisture-loving, keep the soil moist but do not let water accumulate.",
                "fertilizaton": "Fertilization once in spring. ", 
                "pruning": "Fertilization once in spring. ", 
                "plantingtime": "Spring, summer, autumn ",
                "propagation": "Division ",
                "pottingsuggestion": " Needs excellent drainage in pots."
            }
            ],
            "toxictohuman": "Is the aloc plant."
        },
```

Here is the fetching data. I use data class generator for the json to dart

```
class PlantsApi {
  static Future<List<Plants>> getPlantsLocally(BuildContext context) async {
    final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
    final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/plants.json');
    final body = json.decode(data);

    return body.map<Plants>((e) => Plants.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is saying that `snapshot.data` is `null`, are you sure that is returning some data from the request `getPlantsLocally()`?

Comment: i really dont know. i just follow the instruction the I saw. can you please enlighten me to figure it out what is wrong ?

Comment: Move this line: `var users = snapshot.data! as List<Plants>;` to right before this line: `if (users != null && users.length > 0) {` and see if that solves the problem